# CSS -> IE8 filling in background:none child with WHITE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Good afternoon Stackoverflow gurus,

I wish I could show you the exact code for this issue, but I work in a secure area.  I can show you an example.

Here's my CSS

```
table tr.header{
background: url('image.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x !important;
}

table td{
background: none !important;
color: #FFF !important;
}

td.special{
background:url('image2.png'); 0 0 no-repeat transparent !important;
color: #FFF !important;
}
```

The reason for all the importants is that I'm attempting to overwrite a systems god awful bland CSS; simple colors, narrow heights and no pizzazz whatsoever.

Here's my generic HTML

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="header">
         <td>HEADER TITLE</td>
         <td class="special"></td>
      <tr>
         <td>TABLE CONTENT</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I apologize for the `<tbody>` tags, but the system automatically puts `<tbody>` tags in every table.

The problem I'm running into is only in IE8, I have a set image for the table row class "Header" and the all Table Data to show as NO background, but IE8 like to fill the TABLE DATA with white.  I can see the background image of the table row if I go into Developer tools and turn off the CSS for the table data, but there shouldn't be anything in there anyways...

How can I force the table data (except for the one labeled "special") to be 100% clear and transparent in IE8?

Comment: Why would you apologize for the `<tbody>` tags?

Comment: If you're using !important you're on your way to an unfortunate trap. You should read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I force the table data (except for the one labeled "special")
>   to be 100% clear and transparent in IE8?*

Put the following code in an external stylesheet named `ie8.css`.

```
table,
table td {
  background: transparent;
}

table td.special {
  background: url('image2.png'); 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Then add this code to your page.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried background-color:transparent, and I'm getting the same results.  The background element for each TD as listed in IE8's developer tools is as follows:  

`background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%;
background-color: #3B73B9;` 

I even listed the background-color: transparent as !important.  Unfortunately, I think I'm unable to add IF CONDITIONALS.  I'm pretty much modifying a template system of portal sites.  The "template" system is pretty strict, yet boring and sterile.  I'll see what I can do with javascript, but are there any nonIF solutions?

Comment: Also, this may not even be a CSS IE issue, I have a copy of the exact same CSS mods on another site... same CSS, same javascript, same jQuery, and the tables are displaying correctly in IE8.  So my whole disortation about how IE8 sucks might just be a red herring.  I still hate IE8, though.

Answer (score 1):

`background-color:transparent` should work, but it doesn't dig through elements that are under it. If an element under it has a colour, you'll see that colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

at the top of the document (before the `<HTML>` tag). It fixed this problem for me (and moved a load of stuff round too! I hate IE8!).